# Git switching branches preserve untracked folder contents

Tags: git, git-branch

I have the following case:

I have a large web app written in C# and I have two folders that are untracked by git - "App_Data" and "bin". The contents of these folders are specific to the current installation and build of the project. In my App_Data folder I have config files that are specific to my installation, the bin folder is holding the dlls. Whenever I switch branches (that are too far apart in the release history - e.g. between two major versions of the app) the contents of the two folders are outdated and I need to manually delete them and rebuild/reconfigure the project.

What I need is a way to tell git to keep track of the two folders (but not commit them to the repo), and whenever I switch branches to restore the previous state of the the folders for that specific branch.

Comment: Git stores only files, not folders; Git will *create* a folder as needed to store a *file* whose name contains a slash, but internally Git stores only the file names, complete with the slashes in them. For Git to "keep track of" a file, it *must* be stored *in the repository*. So you've set yourself an impossible task: keep track of something Git doesn't store (folders) but not save them (when the only way to keep track of something is to save it). You'll need to find a non-Git solution for that particular problem, or redefine the problem.

Comment: Given that you only really want to do this on major-version switch, and Git doesn't know anything about version numbers, it seems like you should write a non-Git tool to do this. When you want to switch versions, run your non-Git tool, which swaps out the two folders as well as running `git checkout`.

Comment: Consider you might not want to automate the trigger for this, since only you can know when you actually need to swap out those directories. For example, you might switch to a (very) different branch for a few minutes to make a tiny change or even just update a commit message, and you don't need a build for that. When you're done you switch back to your other branch. In that case it might have slowed you down to swap out those directories unnecessarily.